# angular ui mask not working with angular-ui datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, masking

I am trying to use angular-ui-mask with angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker component.

When I use this, the input gets assigned with ng-invalid-date classes even though the date is valid date and date gets cleared after I focus out of the field.

I don't want to use HTML input with `type='date'` as it is not supported by all browsers.

plunker for the same:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dW4AIlF37CLbSHf553d3?p=preview

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ui-mask="99/99/9999" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

Inspect element to see classes assigned to it.

Comment: @Anil Natha, Thanks for reformatting the question.

Answer (score 2):

Luiz's answer was kinda right, but very unclear (if you want the slashes removed).  Since by default ui-mask will strip out the placeholders, you need to send it to the uib-datepicker-popup without them by using: `uib-datepicker-popup="MMddyyyy"`, e.g:

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="MMddyyyy" ui-mask="99/99/9999" ... >
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the placeholder (slashes) you can set `model-view-value="true"`, e.g:

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ui-mask="99/99/9999" model-view-value="true" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use the mask

you need to use the option `datepicker-popup` and provide your formatting in it

```
datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: datepicker-popup provides formatting when user selects date from datepicker control. My requirement is to apply formatting(masking) when user types in the date manually instead of selecting from datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

The ui-mask don't send to backend the fillings, so to use it you will need to do like this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ui-mask="99/99/9999" uib-datepicker-popup="ddMMyyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```